# Built-in Line Output to Interface Line Input on a Mac

Tags: audio-recording, software, logic-pro, hardware

How can I play audio on a Mac (10.11) in a 3d party software instrument (eg. Arturia Synth), piping it through the `built-in line out`, into an analog effects pedal, then record *that* as an `input` through something like a Scarlett 2i2 without getting duplication, feedback, and extra noise in Logic Pro X; all in one shot?

When I try it I get a reverb/echo-like feedback loop when the software instrument stops.

Comment: When you record that back into Logic and listen back to the recording, is the echo/feedback still there?  How long does the echo/feedback last, ie, how many echoes occur?

Comment: It's the latency issue that Tetsujin mentioned in his answer, so it sounds like the dry output with the modded output with a slight latency delay. I was hoping I could get a soundcard with more outputs and inputs and have that fix it or something along those lines, but figured I would try to cut corners with the built-in output first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it cannot be done if you need to also listen to the mix at the same time, through the same output.

Your 'control room mix' *must* be separate from your effects loop, or you're just going round in circles, with your computer's audio i/o latency giving you the time period for the echo you are hearing.

The latency is unavoidable, but if isolated you could slide the recording back into time afterwards, manually.

Your 'fix' is to have an additional output to listen to the mix from.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the answer.